# IOS - Self sizing cells stretch the label views

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel

I'm creating the table view that has these constraints and the self sizing cells.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 400
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

**Main Storyboard:**

[image: Main Storyboard]

**Constraints:**

[image: Constraints]

However, the result makes two top labels stretch like this. Please give me an idea why this happens and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: What is your stackview?...it has ambiguous constraints stackview.top = userlabel.bottom + 8 and stackview.top = imgview.bottom+ 8

Comment: There are two stack views. One contains the Date and MealType labels, the other is above Comments

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing the whole picture, but it likely has to do with the intrinsic content size constraints of that label. Something else is making the size of the cell be larger and the content hugging priority of that cell is low enough that it stretches to fill the space.  Most likely the stretching of that label is a symptom of another problem.

Comment: if I increase the Content hugging priority of these two labels, the two bottom ones will be stretched. It is quite weird that the size of the cell is not dynamic at all.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean about it being a symptom. Something else is dictating a greater height than you expect. If you can post the project somewhere, I can take a look. Otherwise, review the constraints on all items and see what else is making it have a greater height.

Comment: I have pushed it on Github: https://github.com/ZellNguyen/Balance.git. Please take a look, thank you!

Comment: Did you push the latest?  The storyboard looks like the template storyboard.

Comment: Look at the storyboard on GitHub, it doesn't match your picture above at all, just two empty view controllers in a tab controller.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want the `UIImageView` to fill up the empty space. Try adding a height constraint of `>=` a minimum value, say 20(or your font size) to all your labels. And ensure your `UIImageView` has no fixed height constraint but has top, leading, trailing and bottom constraints. These are the constraints you should have:

- User label should have top, leading and trailing `>=` 10. With `numberOfLines` set to 0 and word wrap as the content wrap.
- I'm assuming your date and meal labels are inside a stack view. So it should have a leading, top and height constraint at least that are clearly defined i.e leading, top and height constraint have a priority of 1000. If you are not defining height for this view, it is by default set to 750 and this height constraint will always break.
- Now your `UIImageView` should have top, leading and trailing constraints.
- Your tag label should have a leading, trailing and top constraint.
- Your comments button should have a leading, top, bottom and trailing and a **fixed height**

Apart from the above mentioned constraints ensure all your views **apart from the image view have a fixed height constraint that has a >= to a minimum height**